# Use friendly project reference in xaml to map namespace in related assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Is there a way to reference a VS2019 project by name rather than by the final binary output when mapping a xaml namespace to a related assembly in the same solution?

Instead of:

```
xmlns:abc="clr-namespace:MyStuff;assembly=MyCompany.HelloProduct.v1.0.Controls"
```

It would be a lot more convenient to use the friendly project name as it otherwise appears in the solution:

```
xmlns:abc="clr-namespace:MyStuff;assembly=MyLib.Controls"
```

Shouldn't VS2019 be able to resolve project references like that? Or am I missing something? What do WPF people do when referenced projects frequently change the names of their output binaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom `xmlns` prefix and definition in `AssemblyInfo.cs`, something like that

```cs
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.mycompany.com/xaml", "prefix")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.mycompany.com/xaml", "MyCompany.HelloProduct.MyStuff")]
```

and use it inside XAML like

```
xmlns:prefix="http://schemas.mycompany.com/xaml"
...
<prefix:MyObjectType .../>
```

Have a look at MSDN for details of [XmlnsPrefixAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsprefixattribute?view=netframework-4.8) and [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute?view=netframework-4.8)